# Is it possible to define {$IFDEF} for more than one directive at once?

Tags: delphi, logical-operators, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to define more than one conditional in one {$IFDEF} directive ?
I would like to have syntax like this:

```
{$IFDEF Condition1 OR Condition2} DoSomething; {$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Condition1 AND Condition2} DoSomethingElse; {$ENDIF}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You would need to use [`$IF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_%28Delphi%29) instead:

```
{$IF Defined(Condition1) or Defined(Condition2)}
DoSomething;
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I guess you're not only the lead developer but also a build manager in your company, don't you ?

Comment: @MartinReiner, also the president, the director-general and the senior janitor ;-)

Comment: `{$ENDIF}` instead of `{$IFEND}`

Comment: @Bosshoss not when this was written back in 2012

Answer (score 20):

In case you have to support old Delphis (without the support for the $IF metadirective), you can use one simple and one ugly workaround:

```
//AND
{$IFDEF Cond1}{$IFDEF Cond2}DoSomething{$ENDIF}{$ENDIF} 

//OR
{$UNDEF Cond1OrCond2}
{$IFDEF Cond1}{$DEFINE Cond1OrCond2}{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Cond2}{$DEFINE Cond1OrCond2}{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Cond1OrCond2}DoSomething{$ENDIF}
```

If you are repeating the test more than once, first case should be rewritten as follows.

```
{$UNDEF Cond1AndCond2}
{$IFDEF Cond1}{$IFDEF Cond2}{$DEFINE Cond1AndCond2{$ENDIF}{$ENDIF} 

{$IFDEF Cond1AndCond2}DoSomething{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: old delphis in this context are D5 and older IIRC

Answer (score 6):

hey try this from the [embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_%28Delphi%29)

```
begin
  ...
 {$IF Defined(MY_DEFINE) and (LibVersion > 2.0) }
  Writeln(1);
 {$ELSE}
  Writeln(2);  

  ... 
  {$IFEND}
 end;
```